# Haskell - Negating even numbers in infinite stream

Tags: haskell, infinite-sequence

I am trying to generate a list of infinite numbers

```
0,1,-2,3,-4,5,-6...
```

So far I got

```
evenise x   | x == 0 = 0
            | even x = -x
            | otherwise = x

s = foldl (\x -> evenise x) 0 [1..]
```

However I am getting the error

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a0 = b0 -> a0
In the first argument of `evenise', namely `x'
In the expression: evenise x
In the first argument of `foldl', namely `(\ x -> evenise x)'
```

I do not understand the error since `evenise` takes in an element, and the anoymous function `(\x -> evenise x)` also takes in a single element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `map` not `foldl`

```
s = map evenise [0..]
```

`map` goes through a list and applies the mapped function to each element.  `foldl` is used for "reducing" a list into a value--for example, adding all the elements in a list can be done like

```
foldl (+) 0
```

also, `foldl` only works on finite lists, while `foldr` (also for reducing) will sometimes work on infinite lists.

Comment: omg I did not know I overlooked this. Thank you very much Philip!

Answer (score 3):

You're getting an error because `foldl` takes a function of *two* arguments, not one. But `foldl` can't handle infinite lists anyway, so I don't understand what you're trying to do there.

(You don't need the first line in `evenise` because -0 == 0.)

Comment: Thanks melpomene. I got map and foldl mixed up.

Answer (score 3):

You can also create an infinite list and embed the test into the list definition:

```
s = [ if odd x then x else negate x | x <- [0,1..] ]
```